# Why don't the 6 paths of Pein feel pain?

Tags: naruto

When Ibiki tried to torture one of the six paths of pein, why doesn't she(?) feel the pain? Isn't the pein a living being?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [Ibiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ibiki_Morino) tortured the Animal Path, he realized his techniques were not working

> Ibiki attempted to torture and interrogate the Animal Path, but soon realised that it was unable to feel pain, and seemed to be cold like a corpse.

because the [real Pain](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nagato) is the only one that is living. The different paths are all corpses and controlled though the black roads that are in them

> Nagato created the Six Paths of Pain **out of corpses** that he controlled remotely